# How can I make 32-bit program run on the 64-bit Tails OS?

Tags: 64bit, 32bit, tails-os

Like the title, I want to make 32-bit program run on the 64-bit Tails OS, so I download a package named ia32-libs_2020.05.27_amd64.deb, then dpkg it, but it did't work, the terminal said I should install many packages like gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 and gvfs:i386. However, the Tails4.0 can't install those i386 package... So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Tails is Debian-based so you should be able to follow the instructions for Debian multi-arch systems. Add the 32 bit architecture to your system:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then install the 32 bit binaries, e.g.:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gvfs:i386
```

You can find further information in [Debian's Multiarch HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).